# Benevolent king gives greatest gift: yourself/himself

Tags: myth-identification

Story of a benevolent king (or queen?) who disguises himself among peasants and then reveals himself or is revealed as king and then one of the peasants with whom he interacts thanks the king for the greatest gift a king could give: the gift of himself ('the gift of yourself'), better than gold or something and then this somehow relates to Christianity (perhaps the story came after as a reference to Jesus).

Any ideas please and thank you for the gift of yourself through time, effort, comments or answers? Merry Christmas, and happy holidays!

Comment: Are you sure this is a myth? Do you have any indication as to the area where it came from?

Comment: You might be interested in this article: [The King in Disguise](https://www.jstor.org/stable/1259682?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents)

Comment: @Gibet all you have to do is copy paste. Stop being humble as if your comment isn't good enough for an answer >;P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main thing it: it is quite a typical story. Example: Haroun Al Rashid in 1001 nights exactly did that: being hidden. Fact is: we don't know what he is doing as a king, but during his night we know... That is also a common theme in old egyptians tales. You find the Pharoahs lurking in their cities at nite. Including to pay a visit to their vizir??? ??? Quite common story. Aragorn is another fair example. Richard Lion Heart generally faking being a random bard. Odysseus upon his return in Itaque... – Gibet Dec 21 '17 at 15:53